# Excel Validations - Require a date only if a prior cell is non-blank

Tags: excel, validation

Excel Validations - I know how to use the date validation, but I have a situation where I only want to validate that a date is in column B if there is something entered in the same row in column A. If A is blank B is not required. I imagine I would have to do this in Custom validation rules but not sure how. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Select your entire range on B column and create a custom validation, the formula will be

```
=OR(COUNTA(A2)=0;AND(COUNTA(A2)>0;B2>=DATEVALUE("01/07/2018");B2<DATEVALUE("01/08/2018")))
```

Note that I'm assuming that the second row is your first row for values you need to validate, also the dates I've put are using brazilian date format, but it'll work using yours too. At last, note that your cell references need to be relative (with no dollar signs) so Excel will use the relative position to each cell in the range you're validating (e.g. cell B10 will have A10 and B10 in its formula).

Sorry if my english is bad, but I hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel.    That is close - I think I did not express myself very well.  What I want to do is verify that there is a valid date in B2 if A2 has any contents.  Correct me if I am wrong, but doesn't your example insert one date or another in B2 based on the contents of A2?  If A2 is empty B2 should be too. If A2 is populated the user should have entered a valid date into B2.  I donb't want to plug one in.

Comment: My example lets you insert content in a cell in your B range if: 

a) there's no value in the cell in the same row on column A (counta(value)=0), or;
b) there's a value in the cell in the same row on column A (counta(value)>0) and the value you're trying to insert on B is a date between two dates (value>=datevalue("startdate");value<datevalue("enddate"))

note that for excel nearly every integer (numeric) value is a valid date, so i'm not sure if there's a way to validate if it's a date without set some date limits